# Nginx bind to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: nginx

I installed `nginx-extras` in order to use lua module.
I use [mongroup](https://github.com/jgallen23/mongroup) to group and start services on my machine.

When I run nginx with this command:

```
    exec nginx -c "$(pwd)/nginx.conf" -g "daemon off;"
```

I get:

```
    2015/08/21 12:20:03 [debug] 24217#0: bind() 0.0.0.0:80 #5
    2015/08/21 12:20:03 [emerg] 24217#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed(13:    Permission denied)
```

I have seen some post where it says that I have to launch nginx as root user because only root user can use port 80. So I added:

```
    user root;
```

to my `nginx.conf`.  After this, nothing change and I still get this issue.

Comment: Could you edit the output of `getenforce` into your question?  Which user as you running the `exec nginx` command as? Becoming root means more than just asking for it in a config file.

Comment: Doesn't nginx come with an init script such that it can be started through a more standardized method than this hack?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot open privileged ports (<=1024) as non-root.  Telling `nginx` to run as `root` is nice, but it can't switch to `root` from a normal user itself.  You could run it inside `sudo` to start it as root.  It would be a bad idea to run it as `root` forever so you should put a non-privileged user in there so `nginx` can run without making your machine easier to attack.

Comment: Uset setcap for following capabilities: cap_net_bind_service+eip

Comment: 'You cannot open privileged ports (<=1024) as non-root.' Is that prohibited by the OS or by Nginx?

Comment: the OS enforces it.  see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/linux-allowing-an-user-to-listen-to-a-port-below-1024